# SharePoint Document Library

Tags: sharepoint, document

Can I link to a specific document in a SharePoint document library? As of now, I can only link to the entire document library and not a specific document within it.

Answer (score 9):

Right click on the document and choose 'copy shortcut'. That's your link. You can also click the dropdown -> Send to -> Email a link to directly email the link to someone.

Answer (score 1):

More then that, you can even create a "symlink" on a document by using "Sent to" on the document and select the document library in which you want the "copy" of the document to appear.
You can select whether you would like SharePoint to remind you to propergate the changes from the original to the copies each time you update the original doc.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just append the file name...